# how to freeze the chart while updating continuously in c#

Tags: c#, winforms

> I am using chart control in my c# application.Using timer updating values in chart at every 1 seconds.Also i enabled scroll bar for the chart , so the scroll bar is keep on adjusting while the values are adding. Actually my requirement is if i drag the scroll bar and hold at any point it has to freeze at that particular point only.It should not adjust when ever i drag and hold the scroll bar at the particular point.How to do that ? Please refer the code below,

```
int x1=10, x2=10, y1=10, y2=10; //globally declared
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)  //chart preparation in button click
    {
        chart1.Series.Clear();                         
        series1.MarkerStyle = MarkerStyle.Circle;
        series1.MarkerColor = Color.BlueViolet;
        series1.MarkerSize = 7;
        series1.Color = System.Drawing.Color.Green;                
        series1.IsXValueIndexed = true;              
        series1.YAxisType = AxisType.Primary;
        series1.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line;
        this.chart1.Series.Add(series1);

        series2.MarkerStyle = MarkerStyle.Circle;
        series2.MarkerColor = Color.Orange;
        series2.MarkerSize = 7;
        series2.Color = System.Drawing.Color.Purple;              
        series2.IsXValueIndexed = true;               
            series2.YAxisType = AxisType.Secondary;
        series2.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line;
        this.chart1.Series.Add(series2);

        chart1.ChartAreas[0].CursorX.AutoScroll = true;
        chart1.ChartAreas[0].CursorY.AutoScroll = true;

        chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.ScrollBar.Size = 15;
        chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.ScrollBar.ButtonStyle = ScrollBarButtonStyles.All;
        chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.ScrollBar.IsPositionedInside = false;
        chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.ScrollBar.Enabled = true;

        chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.ScaleView.Zoomable = true;

        chart1.Series[0].Points.AddXY(x1, y1);
        chart1.Series[1].Points.AddXY(x2, y2);
        chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.ScaleView.Position = chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Minimum;// scrollPosition;
        chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.ScaleView.Zoom(chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Maximum - nCheck, chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Maximum);

        x1 += 1;
        x2 += 1;
        nlength++;

        if (nlength == 25)
        {
            nCheck = 30;
            chart1.Update();
        }
        else if (nlength == 50)
            nCheck = 50;

        timer1.Start();
    }
   public void createGraph() //called in timer
    {
        chart1.Series[0].Points.AddXY(x1, y1);
        chart1.Series[1].Points.AddXY(x2, y2);
        chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.ScaleView.Position = chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Minimum;// scrollPosition;
        chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.ScaleView.Zoom(chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Maximum - nCheck, chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Maximum);

        x1 += 1;
        x2 += 1;
        nlength++;

        if (nlength == 25)
        {
            nCheck = 30;
            chart1.Update();
        }                
        else if(nlength == 50)
            nCheck = 50;
    }

    private void chart1_AxisScrollBarClicked(object sender, ScrollBarEventArgs e)
    {
        chart1.ChartAreas[0].CursorX.AutoScroll = false;
        chart1.ChartAreas[0].CursorY.AutoScroll = false; //here i need to update some code i think so ...                    
    }
```

Comment: Is this wpf or winforms?

Comment: _my requirement is if i drag the scroll bar and hold at any point it has to freeze at that particular point only.It should not adjust when ever i drag and hold the scroll bar at the particular point._ Huh? I don't understand! If you keep adding data you may want to set the minimum and maximum values, but really you need to explain the problem better. Also: Your question is not a quote, so don't format it as a quote!

Comment: @TaW - It doesn't sound too complicated.

Comment: @shivcena - Why don't you just stop updating when a drag event starts, queue up the updates while it is happening, and then process the queue when the drag event stops?

Comment: __If you get him right__ this is a good idea. The chart's scrollbars are __special__ and you can in fact  catch a `MouseDown` there..!

Comment: @Enigmativity : Is their any predefined functionality available for queue up the updates for chart

Comment: @shivcena - Not really, it's more or less just an `if` statement, a type you create to temporarily hold your data, and a `List<T>` (where `T` is your temporary data type) that you add to your code.

Answer (score 0):

As long as the minimum and maximum of an axis is not set, it will auto-adjust to data. Here is an example where a start of user selection fixes the range of x-axis to current view and applies the selection as zoom and frees the axis range again when selection is completed.

```
double SelectionStartX=0, SelectionEndX=0;
Chart.SelectionRangeChanging += (object sender, CursorEventArgs e) =>
{
    //Record selection to be applied as zoom in SelectionRangeChanged event 
    SelectionStartX = e.ChartArea.CursorX.SelectionStart;
    SelectionEndX = e.ChartArea.CursorX.SelectionEnd;

    //Stop motion - Fix x-axis range to width of view
    e.Axis.Maximum = e.Axis.ScaleView.ViewMaximum;
    e.Axis.Minimum = e.Axis.ScaleView.ViewMinimum;
};

Chart.SelectionRangeChanged += (object sender, CursorEventArgs e) =>
{

    //Reset previous zooming and apply only last user selected range
    if (e.Axis.ScaleView.IsZoomed)
    {
        e.Axis.ScaleView.ZoomReset();
        e.Axis.ScaleView.Zoom(SelectionStartX, SelectionEndX);
    }

    //Continue motion - Make chart adaptive to data range
    e.Axis.Minimum = double.NaN;
    e.Axis.Maximum = double.NaN;

};
```